# Create new synced calendar with android api

Tags: android, api, calendar

i'm trying to create a calendar on my account to fill with events that i get from some websites. I've searched and found some new android 4.0 calendar example that i've modified to obtain what i need. The problem is that the calendar is created, filled with events but not synced with google calendar, so in the next sync it is erased. The funcion i use are these:

This is the one for add the new calendar if don't alreay exist:

```
public static Uri createCalendarWithName(Context ctx, String name,String accountName) {

            Uri target = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.toString());
            target = target.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google").build();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
            values.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
            values.put(Calendars.NAME, name);
            values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0x00FF00);
            values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_ROOT);
            values.put(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, accountName);
            values.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
            values.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
            values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, "Europe/Rome");
            values.put(Calendars.CAN_PARTIALLY_UPDATE, 1);
            values.put(Calendars.CAL_SYNC1, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + accountName + "/private/full");
            values.put(Calendars.CAL_SYNC2, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full/" + accountName);
            values.put(Calendars.CAL_SYNC3, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full/" + accountName);
            values.put(Calendars.CAL_SYNC4, 1);
            values.put(Calendars.CAL_SYNC5, 0);
            values.put(Calendars.CAL_SYNC8, System.currentTimeMillis());

            Uri newCalendar = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(target, values);

            return newCalendar;
    }
```

and that one create the new event without interaction:

```
public static Uri createEventWithName(Context ctx, long id, String name, String data) {
        long startMillis = 0; 
        long endMillis = 0;     
        int id2=(int)id;
        String[] divisi = data.split("/");
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2012,Integer.parseInt(divisi[0])-1, Integer.parseInt(divisi[1]));
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2012,Integer.parseInt(divisi[0])-1, Integer.parseInt(divisi[1]));
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();


        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Events.TITLE, name);
        cv.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        cv.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        cv.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, id2);
        Log.d("aggiungo a calendario",Integer.toString(id2));
        cv.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().toString());
        //cv.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2");

        Uri newEvent = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv);
        return newEvent;
}
```

I'm not so experienced in Android programming so i think it's a stupid question =) i've read that accountName and Account Type must be the same that the one stored on android device, else the event is cancelled. I get accountName from android api and i think they are correct. The account type seems to work for other....

Thanks to anybody that help me!

Comment: No stupid questions, only ones you don't yet know the answer to :)

Answer (score 2):

Not possible for now.

After a lot of googling I could not find a way to create new syncable calendar in Gmail account (account type "com.google"). I've tried these scenarios:
1. without SyncAdapter and I get the same behaviour - calendar appears in external Google Calendar app with all events I added but shortly after (e.g. after couple of seconds) all events and calendar disappear.
2. with SyncAdapter and com.google authenticator - I get an error during the process
3. with SyncAdapter and com.example authenticator - possible to create calendar but not in Gmail account

Note you can create new account and create new calendar for that account (using SyncAdapter, scenario 3) but it's not a Gmail account so calendar is not syncable with Gmail Calendar (e.g. if you login to Gmail account in web browser and open Google Calendar that calendar you've just created will not show).

Answer (score 2):

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html

> public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL
>
> Added in API level 14 A special account type for calendars not
>   associated with any account. Normally calendars that do not match an
>   account on the device will be removed. Setting the account_type on a
>   calendar to this will prevent it from being wiped if it does not match
>   an existing account.
>
> See Also ACCOUNT_TYPE Constant Value: "LOCAL"

Answer (score 2):

Same issue i was facing. After making the below change now i am seeing the events permanently sticking to my calendar.

In the `addEvent` method add the below line

```
Uri uri =  getContentResolver().insert(asSyncAdapter(Events.CONTENT_URI,"abc@gmail.com","com.gmail"), cv);
```

Code for asSyncAdapter is as below

```
 static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
        return uri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();
     }
```

Comment: Even though I followed the above. It disappears in the google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Javadoc for CalendarContract.Calendars:

"Calendars are designed to be primarily managed by a sync adapter and inserting new calendars should be done as a sync adapter."

If you are not a sync adapter (if you are just an arbitrary app, you are not a sync adapter), that may explain why your new calendar is not getting synchronized like you would expect.