# Insert new calendar with SyncAdapter- Calendar API Android

Tags: android, synchronization, android-calendar

I'm trying to add a new calendar to my google account by using the Android Calendar Provider API. 
 As written in the [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) you have to implement a SyncAdapter to create a new calendar.

So, if I understand things right I "just" have to add a new entry with my syncadapter in the  CalendarContract.Calendars table - but I don't know how to do this.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any examples on how to create a new calendar. (And yes, a googled a lot already).

I would be grateful for even a step in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible for now. I've tried different ways including SyncAdapter, invested a lot of time but without any luck. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734278/237232