# New Google Calendar not getting Synced using sync Adapter

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am creating a new calender in my existing account using this code.

```
CalendarSyncAdapter m_syncAdapter = new CalendarSyncAdapter(this, true);
Account acc = new Account("my_gmail_acc@gmail.com", "www.google.com");
m_syncAdapter.doCreateCalendar(acc);
```

CalendarSyncAdapter class

```
public class CalendarSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    public CalendarSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras,
            String authority, ContentProviderClient provider,
            SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.i("log_tag", "onPerformSync()");
    }

    public void doCreateCalendar(Account account) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        values.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        values.put(Calendars.NAME, "newesttest");
        values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "newestTest");
        values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.GREEN);
        values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,
                Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
        values.put(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, account.name);

        values.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
        values.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);

        Uri creationUri = asSyncAdapter(Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
                account.name, account.type);
        Uri created = cr.insert(creationUri, values);
        long id = Long.parseLong(created.getLastPathSegment());

        Log.i("log_tag", "Calendar created: " + id + " - " + created);
    }

    private Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
        return uri
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(
                        CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
                .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
                .build();
    }
}
```

after executing this code, I could see new calender in device with name `newestTest` but I could not see it on web. please correct me where is I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is Sync set to `ON` in the emulator/device

Comment: @Nezam m running in device, when I created a calender manually in device it synced. Thanks!

Comment: shall i post that as an answer for you to accept?

Comment: @Nezam but it is not syncing when I created calendar through code, and it synced when I created manually.

Comment: i know there's a general issue regarding this.. bdws what was that `thanks` for?

Comment: ohh That was for showing interest in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try force starting the sync operation this way:

```
 cr.requestSync();
```

after you've successfully created the calendar on phone.Give it sometime.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to create new syncable calendar in existing Google (Gmail) account programmatically using existing Android Calendar API. I put more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734278/237232