# How to read events from google accounts calendar in android?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, android-event

I am reading the calendar events in android but i want to read the events for  google accounts calendar events .How is it possible? Could any suggest me or help me out of this?

The below code is working fine and its getting only the android calendar events.How to get the events for google accounts events from  google calendar in android?please help me out of this.

Comment: I am getting the calendar events but i want google calendar events from mobile in android?

Answer (score 0):

you  could try [SignPost](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) for this. It handles OAuth, and you can use it to sign your HTTP requests to get or post data to your calendars.

and here is a guide.
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Hope it helped.

Comment: I think it requires data connection,Do you have any sample code for this without net connection?

Comment: In order to sync your Google Calendar you will need a network operation.

Comment: I've never tried to do it locally but I after looking at Google's API don't think you can do it.

Comment: I've googled a bit it's not possible to create syncable calendar with Google (Gmail) account programmatically using Calendar API for now. SyncAdapter can be used to create new non-Gmail account and create new calendars there but these aren't syncable with Google Calendar.

More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19734278/237232