# Is it possible to create new google calendar from android application?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a new calendar to Google Calendar of the the current user. I tried to use Android 4.0 ICS Content Provider without any success. It is only possible to create local calendar which is not synced.

There are some related questions [Creating a Calendar with Android 4.0's (ICS) Content Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335747/creating-a-calendar-with-android-4-0s-ics-content-provider) but they do not make anything clearer.

Is it possible to create new google calendar from android application or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to create Google Calendar this way. Sync Adapters may be used for own calendar system to make it usable by other application. For example, Google uses Sync Adapter to perform sync with their service.

So when application tries to make any changes for the fields which are opened only for sync adapter it will make no impact on the data.

General answer. You can not create new google calendar. Only google can do this. You may use Sync Adapter only if you develop calendar sync with your own service.